# How to share one fixture among all test classes?

Tags: c#, xunit, fixtures, xunit.net

I want to share DBfixture in all tests. This is the collection created for this purpose:

```
[CollectionDefinition("db")]
public class TestColDefinition : IClassFixture<DBfixture> {  }
```

I have a base class from which i derive my test classes:

```
public class TestBase
{
    protected readonly ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper;
    protected DBfixture dbf;

    public TestBase(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper, DBfixture dbf)
    {
        this.testOutputHelper = testOutputHelper;
        this.dbf = dbf;
    }
}

[Collection("db")]
public class TestClass1 :  TestBase
{
    public TestClass1(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper, DBfixture dbf) : base(testOutputHelper, dbf) { }

    [Fact]
    public void fact(){}
}

[Collection("db")]
public class TestClass2 :  TestBase
{
    public TestClass2(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper, DBfixture dbf) : base(testOutputHelper, dbf) { }

    [Fact]
    public void fact(){}
}
```

But when I run tests two DBfixture objects are created (one for each test class). Without collection four objects are created. How do I setup this so that one object is shared among all test classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the collection fixture and add every test under that collection to achieve what you mentioned above. But if you use a single collection fixture then your entire test will run in serial unless you explicitly disable it in Xunitrunner config.

One of the point from Xunit Docs:
Test collections also influence the way xUnit.net runs tests when running them in parallel.

For more details please read:
https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context

Alternative can be, use a static class to store the DB context which you can assign while starting the test and use that across the test life cycle.

Comment: The problem is in injecting DBFixture. I know it will not run in parallel but the fixture is created two times and that takes considerably amout of time. I don't know why this happens, because I used collection as described in documentation. I don't want to use static members for configuration which should be handled by xunit.

Comment: I think in your code you use both collection and class fixture which might be the reason why 2 DB fixtures are created. Can you check why you mentioned IClassFixture?

Comment: I use IClassFixture only in one place, in the definition of collection.

Comment: If you have provided the DB context in TestBase class constrictor it will be invoked whenever a test is started. Instead, you need to provide that in the collection fixture definition file (not in class constructor).

Comment: Constructor of a test class is invoked for every test. CollectionDefinition ensures that injected variables to the constructor are created only once for the class and a collection. In my example it works for the classes but not for the collection.

Comment: You can't add code to the TestColDefinition. Its purpose is to only mark by interfaces which objects to instanciate and inject later. Additional code will not be used and will do nothing.

Comment: Yes, so the constructor of a test file will get invoked n times if you have n tests in that single file. Collection fixture name definition file will not have any code but you can add code in the place you define the collection fixture class.

Comment: Like this 
public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    public DatabaseFixture()
    {
        Db = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");
    }
    public SqlConnection Db { get; private set; }
}

[CollectionDefinition("Database collection")]
public class DatabaseCollection : ICollectionFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{
}

Comment: Thx, I didn't notice the difference in interfaces.